# Template not showing in Laravel 5.6 and Vue.js 2

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying using vue.js component, but the table template not showing in index.blade.php, I've searched for it in google but it not help me

#### Index.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>@{{6+9}}</h1>
    <employee-component></employee-component>
</div>

<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

#### resource/assets/js/app.js

```
Vue.component('employee-component', require('./components/Employee.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
});
```

#### Employee.vue

```
<template>         
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

#### Result

```
15
```

---

## Solved

#### Has been solved with using

```
Npm Run dev
Npm Run watch-pool
Npm Run watch
```

Comment: can you share any jsfiddle or code snippet or any live demo so that we can reproduce.

Comment: Are you sure about this js is loading `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>`?

Comment: @C2486 i don't know, but in view-source:http://localhost:8000/vueCrud/ app.js is exist

Comment: in example-component (Default) is load in app.js.. but employee-component is not loading, What should I do?

Comment: do you run npm run watch or npm run watch-poll

Comment: @admica Ah, You Right.. thanks, I've edit my vue js.. but the compile showing this..
  <div class="form-group">
    Joko
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6">
    jii
  </div>
  
  
  - Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.